# How to pass custom variables in theme_links($variables) function

Tags: 7, theming

I am new to Drupal. I am currently learning modifying the theme with a sub theme. For that I have created and enabled the sub theme called `ntheme` with base theme `Bartik` . Now suppose I want to pass a custom `css class` to `function ntheme_theme_links($variables)` ? I am basically trying to edit my `menu`. Also let me know if my approach is wrong. Criticisms accepted !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you want to implement a `hook`, `theme`, or `template` function you replace the prefix with your theme or module name, not prepend it.

WRONG: `function ntheme_theme_links($variables)`

CORRECT: `function ntheme_links($variables)`

To add/edit the variables you need to implement a preprocess function like:

```
function ntheme_preprocess_links(&$variables) {
  $variables['your_custom_variable'] = 'your custom value';
}
```